# Does the pattern match in a where clause not only match the LHS part of the pattern expr., but also match the RHS part of the expr.?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I see these code in a tutorial(http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

```
initials :: String -> String -> String  
initials firstname lastname = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."  
    where (f:_) = firstname  
          (l:_) = lastname
```

but I'm confused with here.

```
 where (f:_) = firstname  
       (l:_) = lastname
```

where the 2 patterns are totally same, the only difference between them is the RHS of the equation, one is firstname and the other one is lastname.

So does the pattern match in a where clause not only match the LHS  part of the pattern expr., but also match the RHS part of the expr.?

Comment: It matches the value produced by the expression on the RHS against the pattern on the LHS.

Comment: yeah actually its an assign expression, its not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern:

```
where (f:_) = firstname
```

is equivalent to `f = head firstname`. In particular, it will throw an exception if `firstname` is the empty list.

So the two patterns in the where clause are equivalent to:

```
where f = head firstname
      l = head lastname
```

The function could also have been written this way:

```
initials (f:_) (l:_) = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."
```

and that might make it clearer that `initials` will fail unless both the first and last names are not empty.